# Creating Multilevel Menu at Runtime in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, sql, c#-4.0, drop-down-menu

I have database Structure like below

TblMenu >>

MenuID, MenuName, LinkPath, MenuDesc, MenuPosition, IsParent, ChildID

I am fetching Items at Runtime at Masterpage and want to display items properly with my desired CSS Class but Only Top Level (all items). Now I want to Display Sub-Menu Items also as dropdown. Kindly suggest a way yo get that with ASP.NET and C#.

-John Bhatt

Comment: Provide what you have done so far.

Comment: Kostas, I have generated the Links on Fly using Response.Write method on the ASPX Page. And then binded them with their Links querying from database.